# Classic javascript selector for classes

Tags: javascript

I need to use classic Java Script functions to execute a method when the user clicks on an element with a specific CLASS.

I know how to do this using jQuery. I have no option to use jQuery in current scenario and I am depending on JS alone. Also I need to get the object from where this function is triggered.

```
jQuery(".caller-icon").click(function(){
    var obj = $this;
    // do what I want using obj
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to search for it???

Comment: @A.Wolff I do not know appropriate keywords. so fed up and reached you guys. But thankfully I got replies :)

Comment: I mean typing your title in google would have bring you correct answer... But glad you got good answer here

Comment: @A.Wolff is right, a simple search would have given you answer.  however there was a nice discussion about IE support gone through adeneo's answer that why I love SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.caller-icon');

for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', handler, false);
}

function handler() {
    var obj = this;
}
```

In IE8 and below, you'll need to use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`. If you need to support *IE7* and below, you'll have to do something else, because IE7 and below don't have `querySelectorAll` (or anything else that queries by class names).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - but not `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @ adeneo: [IE8 has `querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector). I didn't think it had `addEventListener`, but you said **below** IE8 (and I don't have it handy to check).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Oh, yeah I meant "below" as in IE7 etc

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I meant below IE8 for QSA, as you just noted in another answer, and below IE9 for `attachEvent`, as I didn't bother looking up  the whole `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` if else thing, as I can never seem to remember it.

Comment: Thank you @adeneo for your quick responses. Let me check and get back here.

Comment: @ adeneo: You can't just lump them together like that, it's misleading. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Thanks, in all fairness I type slow, and english is my fourth language or something, so I don't always write the best (or most logical) explanations.

Comment: @ adeneo: You do pretty well, my man. I just thought at first that I'd missed something important about IE8. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Nope, I don't think you miss much, and IE8 has always been annoying with the `attachEvent` patching.